# Cloud Code Parse.User.current() return null

Tags: parse-platform

When i use this function in Cloud Code `Parse.User.current()` return `null`.
 
I'm using `parseExpressCookieSession` for login.
 
Any advice?

```
var express = require('express');
var expressLayouts = require('cloud/express-layouts');
var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');
var parseExpressCookieSession = require('parse-express-cookie-session');

// Required for initializing enter code hereExpress app in Cloud Code.
var app = express();

// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // Switch to Jade by replacing ejs with jade here.
app.use(expressLayouts);          // Use the layout engine for express
app.set('layout', 'layout');
app.use(parseExpressHttpsRedirect());  // Require user to be on HTTPS.
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('helloworld'));
app.use(parseExpressCookieSession({
  fetchUser: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 * 24 }
}));    

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Menu', function(request, response) {
    var Business = Parse.Object.extend('Business');
    var query = new Parse.Query(Business);

    query.equalTo('profile', Parse.User.current().get('profile'));
    query.find({
        success: function(business) {
            console.log(business);
            response.success();
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error.message);
        }
    });
  });

  app.listen();
```

This the code that i use to login/logout

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password).then(function(user) {
    // Login succeeded, redirect to homepage.
    // parseExpressCookieSession will automatically set cookie.
    res.redirect('/');
  },
  function(error) {
    // Login failed, redirect back to login form.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

// Logs out the user
app.post('/logout', function(req, res) {
  Parse.User.logOut();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

It is an old question but answering for future reference.

**Parse.User.current()** works in Javascript SDK when used in clients ex. WebApp where users log in  and the you can fetch the current user with that function.

To get the user calling a **Cloud Code** function or doing an operation on an object (**beforeSave**,**afterSave**,**beforeDelete** and so on) you use the **request.user** property it contains the user issuing the request to Parse.com.

More details about Parse.Cloud.FunctionRequest here: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.FunctionRequest.html

Example code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('Menu', function(request, response) {
   var requestUser = request.user; 
   // instance of Parse.User object of the user calling .save() on an object of class "Menu"

   // code cut for brevity
});
```

Comment: The link no longer works, and there is no documentation on parseExpressCookieSession anywhere that I can find.

Comment: The link has been updated because Parse changed the URL for their documentation. As for the specific parseExpressCookieSession you will have to contact the original question poster I was just answering the difference between Parse Users used in CloudCode and in Parse JS SDK.